# Angular way of setting up a Dynamic Input field?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui

Let's say there is a text input field that a user will enter an ID into. After that the user will be able to click an "add" button to confirm. Once that button is clicked, the I want to send a send a request to my server and fetch a "name". I want to then disable the text input field, hide the "add" button and display a number input field where the "add" button used to be.

How would I go about structuring this in the Angular way? I have just started using Angular and am a bit familiar with the concepts but am having trouble thinking about this the right way.

Comment: You would probably use something like `ng-click`to trigger a method on the current scope that does the work for you - however, could you show something you have tried yourself so that we may help with more specific problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use ng-show, ng-hide, ng-disabled and ng-click to do this.

The thing you must remember is that you shouldn't edit the DOM directly in your controller. You should use existing directives or create your own directives. In this case, all you need already exist.

You should do something like this :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="textValue" ng-disabled="numberValue"> 
<button ng-hide="numberValue" ng-click="sendData">Send</button>
<input type="number" ng-model="numberValue" ng-show="numberValue">
```

In your controller, you will call your server in the sendData method and assign the result to the numberData property. If you want to disable the button while loading the data, you can add a second property that will be set to true when your start the call to your server and set to false in the callback method of your request. You then add an ng-disabled on that property for the button.

Comment: a++ would read again. I definitely was trying to over complicate things by writing a custom directive for this.